# Publish a web service on Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, .net-3.5

I created a web service in C#, using Visual Studio 2010 ( Framework .NET 3.5). In debug mode it works great, but now I must publish it on the internet, so that I can consume it in remote (the app that will consume the web service is an android app).

So the question is: how do I publish my web service on Internet so that I can consume it in remote?

Thanks in advance; this is a work for taking my degree!

Comment: Do you want to host the service your self or on some service provider?

Comment: if the web service will work fine, i'd like to host the service myself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way: you switch to release mode, update your web.config for production, right click on your service project and from the menu select publish. Then you publish it to the local folder. This way it copies only the files needed. Then you copy the contents of the folder to your remote site using ftp, for example, your hosting provider should have given you the credentials.

for some hosters it is also possible to publish directly but I don't use this.

Comment: Must I have a site to publish my web service?

Comment: If you need it to be available outside of your internal network, to everyone in the world and you are connected from home internet then usually yes. If it is for local network only then you can install Internet Information Services (IIS) on your local pc (if not installed already) and deploy your site there. But configuring IIS would be longer to explain.

Comment: You wrote about "update the web.config for production". May you explain this to me, please? i did not understand how to do it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: It could be that you don't need to do anything, especially in case of a simple service. But often you use some external services, database etc. and then the settings for your development pc could be different from the ones on production server. Yoy usually write such settings to web.confug